# If $g\circ f$ is strictly increasing and $f$ is strictly monotonic, then $g$ has the same monotony as$f$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f, g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions with IVT.If $g\circ f$ is strictly increasing and $f$ is strictly monotonic, then $g$ has the same monotony as$f$?
I believe this is true, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is strictly increasing, then $g$ must be strictly increasing, otherwise we have $x<y$ such that $g(x)\geq g(y)$, so $f(g(x))\geq f(g(y))$, contradiction as $f\circ g$ is strictly increasing.

If $f$ is strictly decreasing, then $g$ must be strictly decreasing, otherwise we have $x<y$ such that $g(x)\leq g(y)$, so $f(g(x))\geq f(g(y))$, contradiction as $f\circ g$ is strictly increasing.

**Edit**: because of a sudden edit. see a counterexample
$$f(x)=e^x,g(x)=x^2,g\circ f(x)=e^{2x}$$
Clearly, $g$ isn't even monotonic...

Comment: My bad,but we have that $g \circ f$ is strictly increasing,I had forgotten to also edit the title of my question,not just its body.I will upvote your work anyway since it was my mistake,but could you help me with the actual question?

Comment: @JustAnAmateur see the edit.

Comment: Thank you for your time and I am sorry again for my initial mistake !